# Neighborhood whose vertices have above average degree

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple, connected, undirected graph with more than one vertex. Proof that a that $G$ contains a vertex $v$ such that

$\frac{1}{|\delta(v)|}
\displaystyle\sum_{w\in{}N(v)} |\delta(w)| \geq \frac{2|E(G)|}{|V(G)|}$

,where $\delta(v)$ is the degree of a vertex, $N(v)$ is the neighborhood of $v$, $E(G)$ is the number of edges in $G$ and $V(G)$ the number of vertices in $G$.

So far if have shown this to bee true for trees where there are always $V(G)-1$ edges,
cycle graphs where there are $V(G)$ edges and I have looked at quite a few examples.

The intuition is that the right side is the average degree for the vertices in $G$ while the left is the average degree of vertices in the neighborhood of $v$.
So proof that there is a neighborhood with above average degree.

I have also tried proving it by removing edges from a fully connected graph or adding edges to a tree but it didn't really work out.

It would be really nice if someone could give me a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you sum the quantity
$$
   \frac{1}{|\delta(v)|}
\displaystyle\sum_{w\in{}N(v)} |\delta(w)|
$$
over all vertices $v$, you will get
$$
   \sum_{vw \in E(G)} \left(\frac{|\delta(w)|}{|\delta(v)|} + \frac{|\delta(v)|}{|\delta(w)|}\right).
$$
You can show that this sum exceeds $2|E(G)|$. Therefore its average over all $v$ is at least $\frac{2|E(G)|}{|V(G)|}$, and there must be some vertex $v$ which achieves at least this average.

Comment: can you elaborate how the first step works?

Comment: If you have a sum over all vertices $v$ and over all $w \in N(v)$, then your sum considers every edge $vw$ once from both points of view (once as $vw$ and once as $wv$).

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Regarding the second step. Is it non obvious or just me not seeing it?

Comment: ok. I got it. It was obvious.