# Neighborhood whose vertices have below average degree

Tags: graph-theory

On a graph with no isolated vertices and with average degree $d$, must there be a vertex $v$ such that the average degree of the neighbours of $v$ is at most $d$?

I am looking for either a proof or a counterexample.

I am taking the average degree of a graph $G$ to be defined as $\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{v\in V(G)} d(v)$.

This is a variation of this question:

[Neighborhood whose vertices have above average degree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3021956/neighborhood-whose-vertices-have-above-average-degree)

This question is relevant to me because it came up in class. I hope it is relevant to our community because it is a very natural question to have in response to the linked post. I understand the proof for the linked post. I was wondering if it could be transformed into a proof of this result via considering the complement graph. I tried to come up with counterexamples but couldn't find any. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. Here is a counterexample:
[image]